# Can you deploy a remix run app to a subfolder?

Tags: remix.run

Normally for nodejs I would run an app in a subfolder using:

```
app.use(config.baseUrl, router);
```

However for remix it's abstracted into createRequestHandler:

```
app.all(
  "*",
  MODE === "production"
    ? createRequestHandler({ build: require(BUILD_DIR),  })
    : (...args) => {
        purgeRequireCache();
        const requestHandler = createRequestHandler({
          build: require(BUILD_DIR),
          mode: MODE,
        });
        return requestHandler(...args);
      }
);
```

Is there any way to configure the base url? Full server.ts:

```
import path from "path";
import express, { RequestHandler, Request, Response, NextFunction, } from "express";
import compression from "compression";
import morgan from "morgan";
import { createRequestHandler } from "@remix-run/express";

const app = express();

const globalExcludePaths = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const paths = [
    '/self-service*'
  ];

  const pathCheck = paths.some(path => path === req.path);

  if (!pathCheck) {
    console.log('Valid path')
    next()
  }
  else {
    console.log('Ignoring path')
  }
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  globalExcludePaths(req, res, next);
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // helpful headers:
  res.set("Strict-Transport-Security", `max-age=${60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100}`);

  // /clean-urls/ -> /clean-urls
  if (req.path.endsWith("/") && req.path.length > 1) {
    const query = req.url.slice(req.path.length);
    const safepath = req.path.slice(0, -1).replace(/\/+/g, "/");
    res.redirect(301, safepath + query);
    return;
  }
  next();
});

app.use(compression());

// http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#at-a-minimum-disable-x-powered-by-header
app.disable("x-powered-by");

// Remix fingerprints its assets so we can cache forever.
app.use(
  "/build",
  express.static("public/build", { immutable: true, maxAge: "1y" })
);

// Everything else (like favicon.ico) is cached for an hour. You may want to be
// more aggressive with this caching.
app.use(express.static("public", { maxAge: "1h" }));

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

const MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const BUILD_DIR = path.join(process.cwd(), "build");

app.all(
  "*",
  MODE === "production"
    ? createRequestHandler({ build: require(BUILD_DIR),  })
    : (...args) => {
        purgeRequireCache();
        const requestHandler = createRequestHandler({
          build: require(BUILD_DIR),
          mode: MODE,
        });
        return requestHandler(...args);
      }
);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  // require the built app so we're ready when the first request comes in
  require(BUILD_DIR);
  console.log(`✅ app ready: http://0.0.0.0:${port}`);
});

function purgeRequireCache() {
  // purge require cache on requests for "server side HMR" this won't let
  // you have in-memory objects between requests in development,
  // alternatively you can set up nodemon/pm2-dev to restart the server on
  // file changes, we prefer the DX of this though, so we've included it
  // for you by default
  for (const key in require.cache) {
    if (key.startsWith(BUILD_DIR)) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-dynamic-delete
      delete require.cache[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `remix-mount-routes`. This allows you to mount your Remix app to a base path other than root.

https://github.com/kiliman/remix-mount-routes